# Is this syntactic tree correct so far?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

*Not homework

I have been doing practice problems, but I am really struggling with syntax trees.

I think I have the first part of the tree, but I'm not sure about the rest.
[image]

Here is the practice questions that I am struggling on:

What is the syntactic tree for the sentence "Who did Nathan think about during the summer?" and if movement has taken place, indicate all movement that has occurred.

Comment: A descriptive grammar tree would be easier to draw and understand. I could draw one for you, but it might get deleted. Let me know.

Comment: No, the subject is Nathan, so it should be in Spec,TP. Move who to Spec,CP